# Making a barrel with geometry nodes. Problems with rotation

Tags: geometry-nodes

Trying to make a barrel with geometry nodes. I'm using the Mesh Circle node as the origin of the points and the cube as the board. But something is wrong with the angle of inclination at the beginning. How to align the boards vertically so that they look like a barrel?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You made it nearly right. You just forgot the align euler to vector node ;)